# Extra output from Javascript nested loop

Tags: javascript

while practicing loop in JS, I wrote following code.

```js
var bool = true;
while(bool) {
  for (var i = 3; i >= 0; i--)
  {
    console.log(i);  
    bool = i;
  }
}
```

The output I expected was:
3
2
1
0
(1 digit per line)

The output I encounter was:
3
2
1
0
0
(1 digit per line)

My question is - how does the code or environment component produce the extra "0"?

Thank you for your time and help.

The observed result is produced in Chrome (F12 -> console tab)
[screen shoot from chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBUFX.png)

Also, on code academy's practice setting. 
And somehow I cannot produce /or observe any result from the "Run code snippet".

UPDATE:

By switching

console.log(i);

and

bool = i;

I got 3 2 1 0 instead.

This would confirm Pointy's answer - no expression, only function call - Thanks again!

Comment: I get `3 2 1 0`. Are you running this directly in the console?

Comment: The output I get is as you expect, in node and in the 'Run code snippet' in your very question.  You're doing something different than you show here.

Comment: @j08691 me too in Chrome

Comment: @JulianFondren try it in Node from the prompt - that is, just run Node and then paste the code into the terminal/command prompt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last `0` is just the console mechanism telling you the value of the last expression statement evaluated. If you change it:

```
var bool = true;
while(bool) {
  for (var i = 3; i >= 0; i--)
  {
    console.log(i);  
    bool = i;
  }
}
"hello world";
```

you'll see `hello world` instead of the last `0`.

Comment: what, the `bool = i`?  which environment echoes that?

Comment: @JulianFondren Firebug, for one, and the Chrome console also, and Node.js too. It's clear that the OP is doing something similar.

Comment: OK, you're citing all of those as behaving as you describe with your code, here, and assuming some similar extra is present in what the questioner is actually doing.  That's cool.  Just making sure that the value of `bool = i` is *not* what would be shown.

Comment: @JulianFondren The value of `bool=i` is definitely what's being shown in those environments.

Comment: As it happens, "hello world" fails the test >=0, so you can set bool to "hello world" in your example, rather than having it as follow the code, and see if that still shows up for you.

Comment: @JulianFondren setting `bool` to `"hello world"` will make the `while` loop never exit :)

Comment: True :p  Also, I pasted the entire code as a single body into node on the command line, rather than run it as a script, and it did display 0 as an extra line of output.  I am corrected.  But node, what shameful behavior!